# Text reader API for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Does it exist an API that would take a string of text, then read it? It would have be a cool feature to offer to people with reading problems. Then they just could tap a button and have it read for them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, iOS has a feature called VoiceOver that can be enabled in Settings (under Accessibility) that speaks items on the screen. VoiceOver will work (to varying degrees) with any app; you can use the Accessibility API to add more information so VoiceOver does a better job of describing the interface.

- [More information on VoiceOver](http://www.apple.com/accessibility/iphone/vision.html)
- [iPhone Accessibility Programming Guide section on VoiceOver](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Accessibility_on_iPhone/Accessibility_on_iPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH100-SW3)

Comment: +1 for this answer. Someone with reading problems likely has this turned on already.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears), I've used it before, it's a breeze to set up (not sure if it's ARC compatible though). It also has voice recognition too.